Template specialization outside an inline namespace of a function defined inside the inline namespace
Is it valid C++ to do a template specialization of a function inside an inline namespace in the space outside the inline namespace?
For example, would this compile?
namespace A
{
    inline namespace A0
    {
        namespace B
        {
            template<typename T>
            T sum(T v1, T v2)
            {
                return v1 + v2;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        template<>
        float sum<float>(float v1, float v2)
        {
            return v1 - v2; // Do something different
        }
    }
}

Currently, this code compiles with g++ 13.02, but not with MSVC 19.40 for c++17

Inline namespaces were actually designed to enable this kind of thing: the idea is that the author of namespace A can switch which subnamespace is the inline one, while clients can continue specializing templates that are declared in one of the subsubnamespaces without being affected by that choice.

https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.def.general#2:

In a named-namespace-definition D, the identifier is the name of the namespace. The identifier is looked up by searching for it in the scopes of the namespace A in which D appears and of every element of the inline namespace set of A. If the lookup finds a namespace-definition for a namespace N, D extends N, and the target scope of D is the scope to which N belongs.

So the second time a namespace named B appears in your example:
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        // ...
    }
}

The lookup finds the namespace A::A0::B, so that new namespace extends the first namespace named B, in exactly the same way as if you had written:
namespace A::inline A0::B {
   // ...
}

Thus when sum is looked up when named in the explicit specialization, it finds the template A::A0::B::sum, which it can specialize fine.

So, I guess it is a bug in the msvc compiler

@TedLyngmo I meant explicit specialization. The lookup happens because https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#3 https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning.general#3.3

@EdwinLesterSolisFuentes Yes, GCC is correct here. Clang also seems to handle this properly.
